# derivative of a diagonal matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, derivatives, optimization, random-walk

> Given the weight graph $G(V,E,w)$ where $w_{}$ is a function which assigns a weight to an edge in graph G, we define the adjacency matrix $A$ by
>   $$A_{ij}=\begin{cases} w_{ij},&\text{if }(i,j) \in E, \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}.\end{cases}$$
>   The degree matrix of a weighted graph is a diagonal matrix $D$ such that
>   $$D_{ii}=\sum_j A_{ij}.$$
>   Which is the derivative of $P=D^{-1}$ with respect to $A$?
>   $$\frac{\partial P}{{\partial\ A}}=\frac{\partial(D^{-1})}{\partial\ A}$$

I was wondering if any one could help me to find out the answer.

Comment: You expect a 3d matrix, right? Note that $(D^{-1})_{ii} = 1/D_{ii} = 1/(\sum_j A_{ij})$. Isn't the answer trivial now?

Comment: If it is a 3d matrix, what is the partial derivative of P_{uv} entry with respect o A?

Comment: For $u \neq v$, don't we have $D_{uv}=P_{uv} = 0$?

Comment: Yes, we do not have.

Comment: In fact I want to know the answer for u=v. I was wondering if you could help me.

Comment: Sometimes I think that everyone doing matrix calculus needs to acknowledge they've scanned [the Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/publication_details.php?id=3274) first ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Let $e$ be the vector whose components are all ones.

Then 
$$\eqalign{
 b &= Ae \cr
 D &= \operatorname{Diag}(b) \cr
 P &= D^{-1} \cr
dP &= -P\,dD\,P \cr
}$$
Those matrices are all diagonal, so apply the diag() operator (which is the reverse of the Diag() operator) to obtain
$$\eqalign{
dp &= -P^2\,db \cr
   &= -P^2\,dA\,e \cr
}$$
Now vectorize both sides
$$\eqalign{
dp &= -\operatorname{vec}(P^2\,dA\,e) \cr
   &= -(e^T\otimes P^2)\,\operatorname{vec}(dA) \cr
   &= -(e^T\otimes P^2)\,da \cr\cr
\frac{\partial p}{\partial a} &= -\,e^T\otimes P^2 \cr\cr
}$$
If you don't wish to vectorize, then you must use higher-order tensors to express the result.

Let $T$ be a 3rd-order tensor, and $F$ a 4th-order tensor, with components given by
$$\eqalign{T_{ijk} &= \begin{cases} 1 &\text{if }(i=j=k) \\ 0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}\cr
F_{ijkm} &= \delta_{ik}\,\delta_{jm} \cr
}$$
Then picking up the previous thread just before vectorization
$$\eqalign{
 dp &= -P^2\,dA\,e \cr
\cr
 dP &= T\,dp \cr &= -T\,P^2\,dA\,e \cr
    &= -T\,P^2\,F\,e^T:dA \cr
\cr
\frac{\partial P}{\partial A} &= -T\,P^2\,F\,e^T \cr
}$$